# Am I allowed to make these kinds of substitutions?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I am trying to solve this:

> Let $$\dfrac{u(x+1)+u(x-1)}{2} = f(x) \tag 1$$
>
> and $$\dfrac{u(x+4)+u(x-4)}{2} = g(x) \tag 2$$
>
> Express $u$ in terms of $f$ and $g$.

My question is if the following steps are justified (I think they're not):

Make the substitutions $x\to x+4$ and $x \to x+1$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$ respectively

Let $$\dfrac{u(x+5)+u(x+3)}{2} = f(x+4) \tag 3$$

$$\dfrac{u(x+5)+u(x-3)}{2} = g(x+1) \tag 4$$

Subtract $(4)$ from $(3)$:

$$\dfrac{u(x+3)-u(x-3)}{2} = f(x+4)-g(x+1) \tag 5$$

I continue and get the solution doing a few more of these substitutions, but I am just not quite sure if the substitutions are valid.

I don't think that I can just combine $3$ and $4$, this is just abuse of notation, right? Because actually I am setting $x=a+4$ and $x=b+1$, so I can't pretend like $a$ and $b$ are independent.

Comment: Your calculation is fine. For any given $x$ equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ are simultaneously true, so $(5)$ is also true for that $x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So I guess if I make the substitution $x=a+4$ in the first equation and $x=b+1$ in the second, $a$ and $b$ are completely independent I guess because they are in different equations? And then more formally I would get $$\dfrac{u(a+5)+u(a+3)}{2} = f(a+4)$$  and  $$\dfrac{u(b+5)+u(b-3)}{2} = g(b+1) $$ and say $a=b$ and the subtract them? Sorry, I don't really know what I'm doing; I just noticed that this pattern of substitutions symbolically leads to a solution, and I am trying to understand now why everything I did is valid.

Comment: If you were to do what you did in the comment, $a$ and $b$ would be unrelated; the first equation holds for any $a$ and the second for any $b$. However, you could then set $b$ equal to $a$, in which case the second equation would become $$\frac{u(a+5)+u(a-3)}2=g(a+1)\;,$$ and you could then combine this with the first equation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok thanks I think that agrees with what I said in the comment above

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: recommend books if you are not getting the style of these problems; here is one of many: https://books.google.com/books/about/Topics_in_Functional_Equations.html?id=7KA-nQEACAAJ    "This book is a systematic and comprehensive approach to functional equations as a whole. Unlike in other branches of competitive mathematics, there is very little theory; "

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$u(x+4) + u(x-4) = (u(x+4) + u(x+2)) - (u(x+2) + u(x)) - (u(x) + u(x-2)) + (u(x-2) + u(x-4)) + 2 u(x)$$